# XSD is not found due to '#' character in path

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I've '#' character in my xsd file path, due to which I get below error:
Message: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '/home/giriyogee/theme#app/WEB-INF/classes/testSchema.xsd'

noNamespaceSchemaLocation is set to above path, which is causing the error. Is there a way to escape # character in noNamesspaceSchemaLocation property?

Comment: I assume that you already verified that it is really the hash that caused the problem? You renamed the path to theme_app, checked that the file really exists and so on? Just asking …

Comment: Yes, I did theme_app and it works fine.  Issue is when my folder name is theme#app.

Comment: hashes have a special meaning in URIs. try replacing '#' with '%23'

Comment: Thanks Sean, it worked fine after replacing '#' with '%23'. As I'm working in java, I further used java.net.URLEncoder.encode(xsdFilePath, "UTF-8") which encodes the path as required.